# matrix form of dummy expansion?

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, matrix, linear-algebra

It's common in many applications to interact a set of numeric variables with a factor variable.  The factor variable is a convenient abstraction for what is actually a matrix of dummy variables.  For example, say I've got a $N\times 3$ matrix $X$ and a 3-level factor $fac$.  In R I could generate the model matrix quite simply:

```
> set.seed(5)
> X <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(10), v2 = rnorm(10), v3 = rnorm(10))
> fac <- c(rep("A",2), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4))
> model.matrix(~ (X$v1 + X$v2 + X$v3):fac - 1)
    X$v1:facA   X$v1:facB  X$v1:facC  X$v2:facA  X$v2:facB  X$v2:facC X$v3:facA  X$v3:facB  X$v3:facC
1  -0.8408555  0.00000000  0.0000000  1.2276303  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.9005119  0.0000000  0.0000000
2   1.3843593  0.00000000  0.0000000 -0.8017795  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.9418694  0.0000000  0.0000000
3   0.0000000 -1.25549186  0.0000000  0.0000000 -1.0803926  0.0000000 0.0000000  1.4679619  0.0000000
4   0.0000000  0.07014277  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.1575344  0.0000000 0.0000000  0.7067611  0.0000000
5   0.0000000  1.71144087  0.0000000  0.0000000 -1.0717600  0.0000000 0.0000000  0.8190089  0.0000000
6   0.0000000 -0.60290798  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.1389861  0.0000000 0.0000000 -0.2934818  0.0000000
7   0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.4721664  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.5973131 0.0000000  0.0000000  1.4185891
8   0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.6353713  0.0000000  0.0000000 -2.1839668 0.0000000  0.0000000  1.4987738
9   0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.2857736  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.2408173 0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.6570821
10  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.1381082  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.2593554 0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.8527954
```

**Is there a way to do this that relies only on matrix algebra?**  Such that I could do something like the following:

```
facdum <- model.matrix(~fac - 1)
identical(X %?% facdum, model.matrix(~ (X$v1 + X$v2 + X$v3):fac - 1))
```

Where `%?%` would be some sort of matrix product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Khatri-Rao product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Khatri.E2.80.93Rao_product) (related to the Kronecker product) can do this. There's an implementation in the `Matrix` package in R, though I don't think it's been implemented in the `%?%` "operator" notation (there's nothing to stop you from doing so, however).

I'll assume there's equal numbers of observations per group, as that's extraneous to the point here, and so that you can construct a matrix mapping groups to observations with a single Kronecker product. Thus everything can be done with "standard" matrix operations (a Kronecker product and a Khatri-Rao product).

```
set.seed(1)
grp <- 3 #number of groups
n   <- 4 #obs per group
k   <- 2 #covariates
Z   <- kronecker(diag(grp), rep(1,n))   #maps groups to observations
X   <- matrix(rnorm(n*grp*k), n*grp, k) #continuous covariates
library(Matrix)
t(KhatriRao(t(X), t(Z)))

#compare to:
fac <- rep(LETTERS[1:grp], each=n)
model.matrix(~fac:X - 1)
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  The lack of terminology was preventing me from expressing my algorithm in math, and complicating various derivations.  FYI your answer doesn't require that the groups have equal observations -- I don't understand your comment about extra matrix multiplication:  `X <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(10), v2 = rnorm(10), v3 = rnorm(10));
fac <- c(rep("A",2), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4));
facdum <- model.matrix(~fac-1);
t(KhatriRao(t(X), t(facdum)))`

Comment: @generic_user Ya, I just meant that if you want to use all known "matrix" operations, you can use the Kronecker product to build the "group design matrix" (Z in my answer). In which case you would need another matrix product to drop rows that you didn't want. If you don't need to express the whole thing as a matrix equation, then definitely `rep(...)` will work fine.

Comment: ... I'll clarify that in my answer.